# Error: read ECONNRESET when connecting from mqtt node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I am facing an issue when trying to connect to mqtt broker, I have installed the mosquitto and given two ports(1883,8883) as a listener in the mosquitto.conf file. When I try to run the code for connect from node.js for mqtts on port 8883 I get below error

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
```

and on mosquitto

```
socket error on client <unknown> disconnecting
```

When I try to publish a message using MQTT.fx it successfully publish the mesasge on port 8883

Below is my code

```
const config = {
  endpoint: 'mqtts://192.168.0.0',
  topic: 'test/topic/local',
  payload: {message: 'HelloWorld'},
}
mqtt.connect(config.endpoint, {
                    clientId: 'some id',
          })
```

Are there some configurations needs to be done?

Comment: Edit the question to include the mosquitto.conf file toy are using and some details of the certificates you are using (are they self signed or issued from a public CA)

Comment: @hardillb, I haven't created the certificates but now I have created the self signed certificates and now it is working by passing rejectUnauthorized: false. I need to ask one thing if I have got a public CA then is it important to pass ca at the client side in node.js connect method? I think it's not important to pass ca at client side, but need to configure the public CA certificate at server side which is mosquitto currently, is my understanding is correct?

Comment: EDIT THE QUESTION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mqtts is the tls version of mqtt , to use it you will need to either supply certs to match the backend or configure it not to validate if they are self signed.

to disable validation add this to your connect

rejectUnauthorized: false

be aware that doing this will prevent your client from being able to validate the backend safely, you should never do this in production.

Comment: passing rejectUnauthorized: false is still giving me 'socket error on client <unknown> disconnecting'

Comment: how have you checked the other end is even listening ?

Comment: Yes I have again checked it and its listening. I have define the listener 8883 in mosquitto.conf with no certificates. When I send message from MQTT.fx client the broker gets the message. But not with node.js moqtt code

Comment: if you are not using certs then dont use mqtts use mqtt

Comment: Thank you. I have created self signed certificates and given the configurations of certs in mosquitto.conf file and rejectUnauthorized: false worked as it is self signed. I have one question is it important to pass the ca in the constructor of mqtt.connect for port 8883 as I have read node.js and its modules have access to hard coded list of root certificates?

Comment: yes your client will need to have access to the CA certificates to be able to validate them, how this is done depends on the OS

Comment: it means it is not important to pass ca in the constructor of mqtt.connect() client as node.js has already an access to hard-coded list of root certificates but that depends on OS?

Comment: The doc for mqttjs has an example of how to pass the CA certificate, follow the link to https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback

Comment: hhmm , you aren't actually using these certs though so there seems little point in passing the CA cert around.